# Two clickable items in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableview as a contact list in which there are a lot of users. It has a thumbnail photo and profile details on each row. I want to make it like when clicking on thumbnail, it goes another page for photo and when clicking on the rest of the space it goes to somewhere else. By using table view delegate I know which row is clicked and pass data, like user id to a new ViewController. But can I know which row when the thumbnail is clicked?

I am using the tag to find the view from cell, like

```
    UIImageView *thumbnailView = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:1];
```

I think I cannot label the row index by tag.

Comment: My table is dynamic and I get subviews of cells by
UIImageView *thumbnailView = (UIImageView *) [cell viewWithTag:1];. If I mark the row index to tag I cannot find the cell when it is used by the following rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can add gesture to thumbnail image and get events on it. Need to set tag for thumb image as per indexPath.row.

Answer (score 0):

Add following code in you in cell datasource method (cellForRowIndexPath:) :

```
cell.YOURIMGVIEW.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
cell.YOURIMGVIEW.tag = indexPath.row;

UITapGestureRecognizer *clickable = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(imageClicked:)];
clickable.numberOfTapsRequired = 1;
[cell.YOURIMGVIEW addGestureRecognizer:clickable];   
[clickable release];
```

And also used below method :

```
-(void)imageClicked:(id)sender
{
      UITapGestureRecognizer *gesture = (UITapGestureRecognizer *) sender;
      NSLog(@"image tag is = %d", gesture.view.tag);
      ////////
      You custome come goes Here !!!!!!!!!!!!!!
      ///////
}
```

Comment: You should set the tag to `indexPath.row + 1` since 0 isn't a good tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the photo as accessory view. Or use a UIButton with the photograph as background and set the action accordingly. (e.g. call a method on the view controller which then performs the push or segue. Doing so you will have to pass some data to the view controller indicating which row was actually clicked in. The number of the row can be used or you can set the tag of the button with some numeric id.)

Answer (score 0):

*Go the Easy way because doing it hard-way won't grant you a president award, right ?*

Instead of `UIImageView` take a `UIButton` and set the Image on `UIButton` instance.

Set Button tag as the `indexPath.row` so that when you retrieve it you know which row is clicked. You can also sort it the other way but it seems quiet handy.

`Add targe`t into the button to a custom function. [ btnObj addTarget ...... ]

`tyepcast` you sender to a `UIButton` and receive the `tag` (indexpath.row)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove all gesture recognizers and buttons in tableviewcell, and in your controller, you can implement below delegate;

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

To make this method triggered, you need to set tableview delegate as your controller, either via code as below, or using storyboard.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.tableview.delegate = self;
}
```

By doing this, it won't matter which item you clicked in your cell, delegate method will be called always.

I hope this helps.